# Match and replace first and last character and substring in string using regex VB NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

Sorry for my simple question but I don't know how to do.

I have this string:

```
Dim SourceString = "{capital?} has a bridge for {people?}"
```

Now I want ResultString like this:

```
ResultString = "capital_Den has a bridge for people_Den"
```

I used

```
Dim str As String = "{capital?} has a bridge for {people?}"
Dim str1 As String str1 = Regex.Replace(str, "\{?\?\}", "_DEN}")
```

Result: `{capital_DEN} has a bridge for {people_DEN}`

But I want this result: `capital_DEN has a bridge for people_DEN`

Comment: Please add the current code with the regex you are using to the question to see where you are stuck.

Comment: Dim str As String = "{capital?} has a bridge for {people?}"
        Dim str1 As String

        str1 = Regex.Replace(str, "\{?\?\}", "_DEN}")
----------------------------------------------------
Result: {capital_DEN} has a bridge for {people_DEN}

But I want this result: capital_DEN has a bridge for people_DEN

Comment: I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\{?\?\}` pattern matches an optional `{`, a `?` and then a `}` char.

You may use

```
str1 = Regex.Replace(str, "\{(\w+)\?\}", "$1_DEN")
```

Or, if there can be more than just word chars inside:

```
str1 = Regex.Replace(str, "\{([^{}]+)\?\}", "$1_DEN")
```

See the [VB.NET demo online](https://ideone.com/Wx7VSG) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7b%28%5cw%2b%29%5c%3f%5c%7d&i=%7bcapital%3f%7d+has+a+bridge+for+%7bpeople%3f%7d&r=%241_DEN). The pattern matches:

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `[^{}]+` - 1+ chars other than `{` and `}`
- `\?\}` - a `?}` substring.

Full VB.NET code snippet:

```
Dim str As String = "{capital?} has a bridge for {people?}"
Dim str1 As String
str1 = Regex.Replace(str, "\{(\w+)\?\}", "$1_DEN")
Console.WriteLine(str1)
' -> capital_DEN has a bridge for people_DEN
```

Comment: Stribizew can you explain what is $1, and how to know which part is replaced by _DEN in this pattern "\{(\w+)\?\}" ?

Comment: @jonathan `$1` is the placeholder (also called a [*numbered replacement backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)) that refers to the value captured in Group 1. Here, `(\w+)` is the [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) #1.

Comment: As I understand that $1 is include anything between "(" and ")", right?

Comment: @jonathan Yeah, the first pair of unescaped parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

**First Make a ConsoleApplication**

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.Title = "Combine"
        Dim a As String = "capital_Den"
        Dim b As String = "people_Mar"
        Dim ResultString As String = a & " has a bridge for " & b
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
        Console.WriteLine(ResultString)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thk for your reply, but I have to replace many times, data to replace get from oracle, include many capitals, so I want to use regex to solve this